# CloudKit subscription internal server error

Tags: xcode, icloud, cloudkit, ios10

I am trying to subscribe to iCloud changes but I keep getting an `internal sever error`. Saving and fethcing data from iCloud works, but I can not fetch nor save subscribtions.

Anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. CloudKit is very poorly documented when it comes to errors. Looks like you receive an internal server error when trying to subscribe for record changes, using a record type which does not exist yet. Weird, hope it helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed that once you encounter an error subsequent calls to CloudKit seem to fail silently. Perhaps its normal iOS behaviour, and I need to reset the error code if it gets set. Maybe someone else can comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the subscriptions working correctly until I added the subscriptionID.  I then started receiving the "Internal server error".  I was using the function:

```
let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: kActionFigureSpecificsRecord, 
   predicate: predicate, 
   subscriptionID: subscriptionId, 
   options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordUpdate, .firesOnRecordDeletion])
```

> subscriptionID
>   The unique name of the subscription. This string must be unique in the specified database and must not be nil.

After reading the documentation, I realized that the subscriptionID needs to be unique, although the documentation wasn't particularly clear regarding unique relative to what.  I believe the unique criteria is with respect to other database ID.names, such as other recordID.recordName.  I had my subscriptionID string the same value as a recordID.recordName for the table on on which the subscription acted for the relevant record.  When I appended _Subscription to the subscriptionID string (i.e., name), the subscription registered fine.